# Why is this position stalemate? I'm new to chess

Tags: rules, stalemate

Why is this position stalemate? I'm new to chess and I played white.

[image: Position]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Black is not in check (which would make the position checkmate) but black has no legal move. This results in a type of draw known as [stalemate](https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/1412/20973).

Answer (score 1):

Stalemate is a situation where the colour that needs to play has no possible or legal way to do it e.g if black moves in your case, he will check himself which is not legal.

Comment: You should add, that "the colour that needs to play" is not in check. (otherwise it would be checkmate).

Comment: @user1583209 oh yeah...thnx

Answer (score 1):

Stalemate is a special type of draw or tie that helps the player that is losing! Specifically, it is a situation in chess where the player whose turn it is to move is not in check, and that player has no other legal moves to make.

Comment: Although stalemate does help the losing player, you must still be a skilled player to manage to force a stalemate. [And stalemate doesn't exist to help the losing player.](https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/1412/20973)